BigQuery NUMERIC type in java showing as java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16] when calling toString()
I have the following part of a Bigquery query:
(SELECT SUM(SAFE_CAST(JSON_VALUE(result.value[0]) AS NUMERIC) AS minutes

when running on bigquery it returns correct number for example 230, now when in Java I try to get this value from the same query like this (SchemaAndRecord contains/is the result of the query):
    @Override public KV<String, Integer> apply(SchemaAndRecord input) {
        GenericRecord genericRecord = input.getRecord();
        Integer minutes = Integer.valueOf(genericRecord.get("minutes").toString());
        return KV.of("key", minutes);
    }

I get the following error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]"

I logged the result of doing genericRecord.get("minutes").toString() and it shows: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]
So im a little confused how to handle this? I managed to make it work by changing in the query like this:
(SELECT SUM(SAFE_CAST(JSON_VALUE(result.value[0]) AS INTEGER) AS minutes

but I do not understand what is wrong with the NUMERIC type in my case, would like to understand and also see if there is a way to make the java code work keeping NUMERIC in the query

NumberFormatException occurs when you cast String type to Number type.
I think 3rd line is the problem. Integer.valueOf() parse String into Integer internally but if it exceed the range of Integer, throw NumberTypeException.
So i recommand you to try converting it to a Long type or BigDecimal type has a wider range.
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(num);

I hope it was a range issue.

This does not explain how the ByteBuffer came about in the first place.
